# A script for file transfer

Tags: bash, exchange-migration

Here is my script which I have created for transferring particular types of files from directories. I am struggling to find a way to move the file to archive directory with current time stamp.

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER='abc.com'
USER='xyz'
PASSWD='lddkdkdkas'
find /directory/ -name ABC002*.csv | while read fname
do
   scp $fname xyz@abc.com:~/XYZ/
   mv $fname ./archive/
done
```

Here I can move the file to archive, but I am not able to move it with name changed to filename *timestamp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

`mv $fname ./archive/$(basename $fname)-$(date +%Y%m%d-%T)`

Comment: Quotes are recommended: `mv "$fname" "./archive/$(basename "$fname")-$(date +%Y%m%d-%T)"`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
mv $fname /tmp/`basename $fname`-`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
```

You can use variations of this theme if you prefer different timestamps or filenames.  Be aware that this solution is not robust enough to handle multiple filenames.

Comment: The problem with this is that $fname is a complete path of file.

Comment: My mistake, answered too quickly.  Corrected.  (Before anyone else did.)  =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
mv $fname ./archive/`date +%m%d%y-%T`-$fname
```

There are single backticks in front of date and after T 
They do not show up in post for some reason

Answer (score 1):

You might need to use the `basename` command to strip the complete file path.

Also you might want to use an array to generate a list of files to move later; or even to use the `-exec` option of `find`, something like:

```
find /dir -iname BLAH -exec sh -c 'new_name=$(basename {}); scp {} user@host:dest/ && mv {} /archive/$new_name$(date..)' \;
```

(don't forget the `\;` at the end)

That line archives the file only after (`&&`) a successful copy over ssh.

Another hint: perhaps you want to `tar` the files and send a compressed archive over the network? This might save you the ssh handshaking time (and use ssh keys! don't save passwords in scripts you will leave around!)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, that password thing was default there in my script when I was trying to using password login to remote server, but I have adapted to passwordless login scheme using public key.

Comment: That won't work at all. You need to use `sh -c` or `bash -c` and some quoting. You're missing a dollar sign on a variable. There's no need for a variable that you're only using once. Just use `basename` directly where it's needed.

Comment: @Dennis fixed typo. The extra variable name is for clarity and for hope it could be used later on (say, print it in a log file). Anything else won't work?

Comment: Most shells won't accept spaces around the equal sign. The parentheses would create a subshell (if they didn't cause an error) which means the variable's value won't be available outside it. `find` can't set variables in its `-exec`. You need to use `sh -c` or `bash -c` to make the variable assignment and expansion work, but that also sets up a subshell so the variable's value won't be available outside it. The variable near the end will be expanded before the `find` is run, not during, since it's not escaped. I think that's a complete list. The following might work:

Comment: `find /dir -iname BLAH -exec sh -c 'new_name=$(basename {}); scp {} user@host:dest/ && mv {} /archive/$new_name$(date..)' \;`

Comment: @Dennis: thanks. I fixed it. Next time I promise I'll test it first, or wait til I have a shell to try it on.

Answer (score 1):

Add a basename to Warner's answer:

```
 mv $fname ./archive/`basename $fname`-`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M`
```